# Wasteland exploration

Tags: fallout-shelter

I know there are a lot of questions about the wasteland in fallout shelter
I only have one problem  not sure if it can be answered directly. I currently have one dweller out exploring the wasteland. He's name is Jericho. He has been out for 3 days... not finding anything. He has high L,S,E and P after I trained him so he should be finding good items? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Earlier today I send out one dweller that came in from the wasteland because of the radio station, I give him a rusty BB gun and check on him an hour later and guess what he has found?... A guided fat man. This should not be possible right?

Comment: Consider every event in the wasteland no different from flipping a lunchbox card. You might get amazing new legendary gear, but you're probably just going to get something lame like a few bottlecaps.

Answer (score 5):

Results from the wasteland are mostly random. It is **highly unlikely** (but **not impossible**, as you have the proof in your game) that a level one dweller with wimpy stats comes across the most powerful weapon in the game in an hour of exploration. Your badass explorer with top stats and elite gear might not see that type of weapon after exploring for a week. This is how the RNG works.

Because of the randomness, there is no formula that guarantees that a dweller with X stats and Y gear explore for Z time period will come back with the **best** loot. What we do know is that having better SPECIAL, a higher level, and exploring for longer periods of time make it **more likely** that the dweller finds **better** gear, more caps, and earns more experience than another dweller with lower stats exploring for a shorter time period finds. You can see this at work by looking at the results after multiple explorations. Jericho may not be bringing back plasma weapons and fat men every time, but he should be reliably finding shotguns, rifles, and the like rather than rusty pistols.

The other factor that you haven't mentioned with Jericho is his level. Results in my game suggest that the level of the explorer may also factor into the quality of loot they find (although part of this is that lower level wanderers just can't survive very long). My lower level explorers tend to find mostly pistols, maybe

### tl;dr

Yes it's possible. Congrats on your guided fat man. With repeated expeditions, the results should be more in line of better stats + more time = better loot, but there is no surefire way of getting the absolute best loot every time. Improve your SPECIAL, improve your level, send out for as long as possible, pray to the RNGods, and send more expeditions. Eventually you will get what you are looking for.